# Am I doing the dynamic memory allocation correctly without doing any memory allocation for unnecessary space?

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

How much memory gets allocated for the stack dynamically for this code?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

#define max_size 100

typedef struct stack
{
    int top;
    int capacity;
    int items[max_size];
} stack;

stack* initialize(stack *s, int capacity)
{
    s = (stack*)malloc((capacity)*sizeof(int) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(int));
    s->top = -1;
    if(capacity<1)
        cout<<"invalid capacity !"<<"\n";
    else
        s->capacity = capacity; 
    return s;
}
```

I tried to avoid any extra memory allocation. I didn't use this line of code:

```
stack *s = (stack*)malloc(sizeof(stack));
```

because it will create a stack of `max_size` of items. **I want to strictly allocate memory for a stack which holds `capacity` number of items.** Is this the right way to achieve my goal? If it's not, then please provide me with the better code possibly with a modified structure definition. I'm getting the desired results for my code.

Comment: No the allocation is not correct. You must use `sizeof(stack)`. See [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

Comment: With all this said, if you want to be able to resize the `items` array, you need to manage its memory separately. So with a pointer and a separate `malloc` call.

Comment: Are you trying to use C or C++? This is wrong in either language, but the best solution might be different depending on language.

Comment: Oh and you're programming in C++, in which case you should not use `malloc` and `free` at all. Preferably you should be using the standard C++ `std::stack`. And if your assignment is to implement your own stack then use `std::vector`. And if that's not allowed use `std::unique_ptr`. And if that's not allowed, use `new[]` and `delete[]` instead of `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: @Ludin : I'm using C++ but I'm looking for the solutions in both C and C++.

Comment: C and C++ are just not the same language. You should not try to create code that caters to the few common bits, since even those are different in each language. For example, in C++ it's usually considered a flaw to have a C-style explicit conversion (a "cast") like is required for the result of `malloc`, while in C you [should not cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/should-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). If you try to conform to both languages, the code will be bad in both languages. Pick ***one*** language, and stick with it.

Comment: Also please read [the `c++` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) about using the `c++` and `c` tags together. Your question doesn't follow those guidelines.

Comment: No you are NOT doing it cocrrectl. NEVER use malloc/free in C++. Try to write code that does not rely on manual dynamic memory allocation at all. C++ has std::vector, std::string, std::list, std::stack (and more) which all help you to avoid that. If you ever do need memory allocation use std::make_unique (or std::make_shared)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`malloc((capacity)*sizeof(int) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(int));`

This will not work, the compiler expects `capacity` to be exactly 100 items, statically, since you declared the array member as such. You cannot underallocate memory for the struct and expect the program to behave in a certain way - it's undefined behavior in either language.

- The correct solution for C++ is to use `std::vector` or `std::stack` etc instead. You should never use `malloc` in C++ programs: it is plain dangerous since it doesn't call constructors etc and `struct` in C++ is just a poor man's class.
- The correct solution for C is to use a *flexible array member*:

```c
typedef struct stack
{
    int top;
    int capacity;
    int items[];
} stack;

...

stack *s = malloc( sizeof(stack) + sizeof(int[capacity]) );
```

Comment: It works. Could you please share an equivalent solution using the 'new' keyword?

Comment: @Debbie: That's impossible. C does not have the `new` keyword, and C++ does not have flexible array members.  As we've been telling you, pick a language. C++ doesn't even need `new` for this, it has `std::stack`.

Comment: I'm trying to find a solution in both the languages. I'm not allowed to use STLs for C++. Everything has to be written from scratch.

Comment: @Debbie Then you'll have to resort to `int* items` and init it with `... = new int[n]` from the constructor etc (remember "the rule of 3").